# Only Available SDK Target is Android 4.4W?

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded the Eclipse ADT with Android SDK from the Official Android Site: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i
However in my SDK location upon opening the new eclipse, points to a location:

```
 \adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk
```

That only has Android 4.4W installed and no other SDK Targets? 
This is causing problems because I couldn't choose any AVD inside eclipse.
I also couldn't start up "SDK Manager" getting the following error:

```
[2014-11-15 11:32:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Error: Unable to access jarfile lib\archquery.jar 
[2014-11-15 11:32:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path 
[2014-11-15 11:32:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified. 
[2014-11-15 11:32:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified. 
[2014-11-15 11:32:53 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified
```

Comment: "I also couldn't start up SDK Manager" -- I would focus on that problem, as that is how you download other pieces of the Android SDK, including emulator images for your AVDs.

Answer (score 2):

All the android sdk's you'd download now from the developers.android.com website would contain the 4.4W installed by default. Frustrating, I know. So you need to download additional SDK's before you can begin coding apps for phones unless you're planning on developing for the `android wear`.

What I would focus on, by the way, is `I also couldn't start up "SDK Manager"`. This may be a problem, indicating that something is not working properly. Try running the SDK Manager directly from the `adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\` folder. If that doesn't work, (which by the way, should work), try running it from within eclipse. If both fails, try removing everything and re-downloading the SDK from the website again.

Comment: I'm trying to open up "SDK Manager.exe" from Windows Explorer. However nothing happens. Where can I see the error log associated with these types of inactivity?

Comment: Do you have any ideas, or have ran into this problem as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had been searching for this but I have not been able to find any appropriate work around. Neither was I able to create a situation like yours on my machine. I tried downloading the ADT from their site and installing it on a different machine and things worked fine. I was able to launch the SDK Manager. I am still trying to find a solution to your problem. Try running the SDK Manager in administrator mode. It this fails too, try removing everything and unzipping the downloaded ADT again.

Comment: Btw, where is your Android SDK Manager located? i. e., the file location.

Comment: I have the same problem in Mac OS, shall i removethe SDK ?

Comment: @Emna, when did you download the SDK, because as of now, the present downloadable SDK does not come with 4.4W.

Comment: @SajibAcharya : i have downloaded the latest version of SDK, but i always find only 4.4 W and no system images even if i download different packages (5.0.1 or 6.0 ... ) i'm always having the same pb ! 
is it possible because i have already this one adt-bundle-mac-x86_64- 20140702 ? (i'm using the sdk path in that folder )

Comment: @Emna, first, are you downloading the SDK from the [official website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)? Next, if so then tell the procedure how you are downloading the SDK. I am guessing you already have a previous SDK downloaded and installed.

Comment: So what shall i do  in the case i have a previous and i install a new one(because i'm sure i download it from the official site  ) ?

Comment: @Emna, if you are using Android Studio, which I guess you most probably are, and if you already have a previous installation, you do not need to download a new SDK. What you can do is open the SDK Manager tool (from Android Studio) and then download new available API versions from the SDK Manager itself and keep your copy of SDK updated with the present releases.

Comment: @SajibAcharya : Thanks i will do it.

Comment: @SajibAcharya i did all what you told me then i close the android studio and i tap into the terminal android avd always i got only the same choice which is Android 4.4 W (Api 19) when i select it i found no image system here ... 
why the ones i have installed didn't appear?

Comment: @Emna, when you installed Android Studio, did you mention in Android Studio that you already had an existing installation of the SDK and did you  reference that during the setup  process?

Comment: I choose the sdk folder i told you inside the  adt-bundle-mac-x86_64- 20140702 in downloads folder, It tells me that it is up to date. 
I have a doubt about this folder  adt-bundle-mac-x86_64- 20140702, is it correct to use it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109710/discussion-between-sajib-acharya-and-emna).